# How to create a submitted CGI::FormBuilder object?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, cgi, formbuilder

I have a method that takes a cgi object and creates a CGI::FormBuilder object. if it is submitted, does a db connection and process data otherwise, prepopulates some data and renders the form.

I want to write a unit test for it. Therefore, I want to give it a cgi object and it will create a submitted form and process data.

Which parameter must be specified in cgi to do form to be submitted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: found it: (submittedname_of_the_form)_(name_of_the_form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter is (submittedname_of_the_form)_(name_of_the_form)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want:

```
$q = CGI->new(INPUTFILE);
#or
$q = CGI->new(\*STDIN);
#or 
$q = CGI->new($my_query_string);
#or
$q = CGI->new(\%my_form_params);
```

[As described on CPAN CGI page](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.55/lib/CGI.pm)

Comment: I wanted to create a cgi object one of the way you described above but the actual thing I wanted to learn which parameter I should provide in cgi object to formbuilder to be processed as submitted. I had already found and added what I wanted as a comment since it prevented me from adding as an answer in the first 8 hours.